# Put image to page without using import statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I download an svg to my img/bodygraphs folder with node server/axios. This svg has a unique name - userName + userFamilyname + .svg (e.g. JohnSmith.svg). Next I'd like to display it from that folder as then I have to use pieces of this svg at my page. Thing is, I can't do that. When I try to display image using `` <img src={`./img/bodygraphs/${this.state.firstName}${this.state.lastName}.svg`} /> `` no image is displayed. I've even tried it with fixed filename, say `<img src="http://localhost:3000/img/bodygraphs/SomenameSomefamilyname.svg" />` - still nothing

But when I import it with `import bodygraphsvg from './img/bodygraphs/SomenameSomefamiyname.svg';` and then `<img src={bodygraphsvg} />` it works like charm. So how can I put this image to page without using the import statement as filename is changing with each new user?

Comment: How is your node server configured? Are you using express?  express.static with a public directory, where images are stored?

Comment: @Tore yes, I'm using express. I think the problem is somewhere in my static declaration that looks like this:

`app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use('/img/bodygraphs', express.static(__dirname + '/img/bodygraphs'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`
And when I try to access localhost:3001/img/bodygraphs it says that it can't GET it

Comment: @Tore tnx for pointing out the express.static. I've figured out that I've used wrong static path. Problem solved